# Windows 10 Network Driver issue

Tags: windows-10, drivers, gigabit-ethernet

For the past week or so, I've been having an issue with getting an Intel LAN Driver working on Windows 10 1903. I've uninstalled the official Intel drivers and let Windows use its own, then reinstalled the official drivers again, have done this many times over and the Intel I211 Gigabit Ethernet controller still throws out a Code 10. I have attempted to just manually install Intel's official "inf" file while also blocking the device ID using Local Policy Editor thinking Windows was somehow interfering with the driver install and that also did nothing, i did change that policy back to normal after that.

This is not the first time it happened either, I was able to get the functionality of the Ethernet driver back by doing a system restore, doing this did not help this time, however.

---

To clarify, this is my system:

```
Motherboard: MSI X470 Gaming Pro Carbon
OS: Windows 10 1903
Net Controller: Intel I211 Gigabit
```

Here's some screenshot links to get a better idea of the problem

[One driver being marked as unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7lHy.png)

[When official Intel drivers are uninstalled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7W8e.png)

[Screenshot of the Code 10 for good measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiT22.png)

I have already tested the ethernet port and know that it works when loading up a Linux live disk (Fedora 30 in my case), so the Ethernet port isn't physically dead.

Comment: Your choosing the option to remove the driver entirely from the device (I.e not choosing to simply uninstall it which doesn’t remove the driver).  Has this device ever worked on the version of Windows 10 your running?

Comment: I also deleted the additional drivers in Device Manager by checking the checkbox in the window that pops up when uninstalling the device, but yes, it has worked on 1903 ever since I reinstalled about 4 months ago, until some update broke it in early October, I was able to roll back the damage with System Restore, not this time.

Comment: Are you sure your running 1903, because the only update that would cause a driver incompatibility problem would be the November 2019 (1909) update.  The Intel release notes provide specific guidance for 1809+.  “Intel(R) PROSet for Windows* Device Manager is not supported on 
Microsoft* Windows Server* 2019 (and later) and Microsoft Windows* 10 Version 
1809 (and later). Use Intel(R) PROSet Adapter Configuration Utility instead. 
The installer will determine which utility to install based on the operating 
system you are running.” Have you used the configuration utility tool?

Comment: The tool seems to be installed from this package [Here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25016/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-Windows-10?product=46827)

Comment: Just checked, Windows still reports a 1903 Build. However, there was a particular Update KB that kept breaking the driver, I system restored to a point prior to it being installed before, this time I can't even do that get the functionality back.

Comment: Have you used the [Intel Network Adapter Driver for Windows 10](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25016/Ethernet-Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-Windows-10?product=64403)?

Comment: Yes, yes I have, same thing

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the issue, apparently SecureBoot was preventing Windows 10 from validating the network driver, what I had to do was switch my motherboard's boot mode to CSM instead of UEFI.